# Why is it valid to pass address of member in temporary object?

Tags: c++

Considering the following code.

```
struct MyVARIANT
{
    VARIANT var_;

    MyVARIANT(unsigned uVal) {
        VariantInit(&var_);
        var_.ulVal = uVal;
        var_.vt = VT_UI4;
    };

    ~MyVARIANT() {
        VariantClear(&var_);
    }

    VARIANT* operator&() {
        return &var_;
    }
};    

HRESULT SetValue(VARIANT* val)
{
    return S_OK;
}


void foo()
{
    SetValue(&MyVARIANT(1u).var_);
    // E0158    expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
}

void bar()
{
    SetValue(&MyVARIANT(1u));
    // Fine
}
```

There are many WIN32 API calls required `non-const VARIANT*` as parameter type. So I meet this problem when I try to pass the `VARIANT*` from my VARIANT wrapper.

Compiler complains the `foo()`, because I pass the address of data member of temporary object by `operator &`, which is not a l-value.

But when I overrided the `MyVARIANT::operator&` to pass the internal member's address, the compiler does not complain this way in `bar()`.

What is the difference between

```
&MyVARIANT(1u).var_
```

and

```
&MyVARIANT(1u)
// same as MyVARIANT::operator& (&MyVARIANT(1u)) { return &this->var_; }
```

?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what you're doing in overloaded `operator&`; you might also return an invalid pointer.

Comment: So my `operator&` may be UB when accessed from temporary object?

Comment: There is no UB here, calling a member function on a temporary object is fine.

Comment: You *could* trigger UB there as in anywhere else, but there is no issue in your code (except for the usual weirdness about `operator&`, consider an implicit conversion or a getter instead).

Comment: @VTT Yes, you're right. It's not UB untill trying to dereference on the returned dangled pointer.

Comment: @songyuanyao but that pointer is not dangling, the temporary lives until the end of the call to `SetValue`.

Comment: @songyuanyao The pointer returned will become dangled only after temporary object is destroyed, which happens after pointer is used. The given code is fine as long as `SetValue` method is not storing that pointer value for later use.

Comment: @Quentin It's interesting; then the 1st code sample should be fine too.

Comment: @songyuanyao 1st code sample is not fine because taking an address of a temporary is not permitted.

Comment: @VTT But the code should be safe for the same logic. So it's just banned by the standard?

Comment: @songyuanyao The issue is with temporary materialization and value category.

Comment: @songyuanyao I think an operand of an address of operator being required to be an lvalue is a C heritage. C++ only adds a freedom to call member functions on temporaries.

Comment: @VTT Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is legal because C++ is protecting you only from known risky constructs. The `&MyVariant(1).var` pointer definitely points to the member of a temporary.

`MyVariant(1)::operator&()` on the other hand is calling a user-defined function. The compiler isn't going to guess at the implementation of that function; it's a legal call in the given context.

Comment: _"C++ is protecting you only from known risky constructs"_ that's news to me :)